# How to use ptrace in 64 bit process to modify registers in a 32-bit process and make it do a system-call?

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, system-calls, ptrace

I'm working on a program that needs to make a 32 bit process invoke a syscall.
I wish to keep my program architecture independent, but the target will always be 32 bit.

To set the registers I'm using `ptrace` with `PTRACE_SETREGS`, which takes regs struct pointer as its data argument.

x86_64 and x86 have different definitions for `struct user_regs_struct` so I've tried simply using the x86_64 on, which passes the syscall number correctly but none of the arguments, I have verified this by passing `1` (__NR_exit on x86) as the syscall number and `21` as the first argument, but the process only exits with 0.

I have also tried copying the x86 definition for `struct user_regs_struct` with that only causing segfaults.

Since the two definitions of the struct use completely different data types (`unsigned long long int` on x86_64 and `long int` on x86) I doubt its implicitly accessing the right data, but it doesn't appear to be using the same registers as x86_64 does for arguments (rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, and r9).

Comment: So your real question is how to access the registers of a 32-bit process with `ptrace` in a 64-bit process?  That's not specific to system calls.  Your actual question title sounds like you want to run `syscall` in a 32-bit process with `__NR_xyz` from `unistd_64.h` (and EDI, ESI, etc. registers) instead of `int 0x80` or `sysenter` with numbers from `unistd_32.h`, or something like that.  Or somehow get the kernel to call the 64-bit system-call implementation function instead of the IA32_EMULATION wrapper.

Comment: More or less. I'm trying to run `syscall` but not with the 64-bit syscall numbers.

Comment: In 32-bit compat mode (under a 64-bit kernel), only AMD CPUs support the `syscall` instruction.  On Intel CPUs, it will #UD fault, so the kernel delivers SIGILL.  Why do you want to use it instead of letting the VDSO use `sysenter` or `int 0x80` after you override the args to the 32-bit system call like your question and answer talks about with `struct user_regs_struct`?

Comment: I know that, I'm abstracting both `syscall` and `int 0x80` as a general "run a syscall". I check the program architecture at runtime and use the right one depending on it.

Comment: My general problem here was that I did not correctly understand what x86_64 registers were the equivalent of the x86 registers, so instead of writing to `rbx`, `rcx` (x86_64 equivalent of the x86 syscalls registers) I wrote to `rdi`, `rsi` (registers used on x86_64 syscall).

Some of the x86_64 registers don't exist on x86 and were thrown out and others mapped over, but were in the wrong position (e.g. `rdi` (first argument on x86_64) maps to `edi` (5th argument on x86)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As luck would have it, I couldn't figure this out for days, but as soon as you ask the question you realize what you should be doing.

You just have to use the x86_64 equivilant of the registers.
So, for example
`eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi`, `edi`, `edp`
becomes
`rax`, `rbx`, `rcx`, `rdx`, `rsi`, `rdi`, `rdp`